# how to get the specific format in crossfilter.js i.e distinct of distinct count

Tags: crossfilter

this is my format of data:

```
[{city:"Bhopal",id: 1},{city:"Bhopal",id: 2},{city:"Delhi",id: 3},{city:"Delhi",id:3}]
```

here i have **Delhi** repeated twice with same id.

now i need distinct count of **city** where **id** is distinct i.e like :

```
[key:"Bhopal",value:2, key:"Delhi",value:1]
```

where **value** is count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the answer using [Reductio](https://github.com/crossfilter/reductio) and [Crossfilter](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter).

```
var payments = crossfilter([
  {city: "Bhopal", id: 1},{city: "Bhopal", id: 2},{city: "Delhi", id: 3},{city: "Delhi", id: 3}
]);
var dim = payments.dimension(function(d) { return d.city; });
var group = dim.group();
var reducer = reductio()
    .exception(function(d) { return d.id; })
    .exceptionCount(true);
reducer(group);
console.log(group.top(Infinity));
```

output: [ { key: 'Bhopal', value: { exceptionCount: 2 },{ key: 'Delhi', value: { exceptionCount: 2 }]